# How to plot several data progeress on x axis?

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have data over time for different position and need to plot it like this:

[Plot data for certain position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvS9U.png)

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: what package are you using

Comment: I'm using matplotlib if that was what you were asking for :)

Comment: If you are new to SO, please see [ask] and [reprex] and maybe take the [tour]. They'll help you ask quality questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just reverse the x and y data?

```
data = np.random.uniform(-0.01, 0.01, (20, 3))
xc = [0.26625, 0.28375, 0.30125]
for i in range(3):
    plt.plot(xc[i] + data[:, i], range(20))
```

[image]

Comment: Problem is that I have certain position on the x-axis, where it should be place and the values of each data is almost the same so you can't shift it like this.

Comment: can you share your data? The one in your figure has different x values.

Comment: I have posted is

Comment: so what is this "certain position" that you are referring to?

Comment: Those coodinates in the list xc

Comment: Yeah you are right, sorry I'm new to stackoverflow. The value of the data is irelevant for what I need. I just want to show the course of the data at the positon xc. In the first picture you see, that the amplitudes of the data are bigger for a greater xc and that is what I want to show. But the code you have updated is really helpful! I can just shift my data by adding a value to it. Thank you!